# Ansible change ssh port in playbook

Tags: ansible

Here is the inventory file

```
---
[de-servers]
192.26.32.32

[uk-servers]
172.21.1.23
172.32.2.11
```

and my playbook is look like this:

```
- name: Install de-servers configurations
  hosts: de-servers  
  roles:
    - de-server-setup

- name: Install uk-servers configurations
  hosts: uk-servers  
  roles:
    - uk-server-setup

- name: Do some other job on de-servers (cannot be done until uk-servers is installed)
  hosts: de-servers
  roles:
    - de-servers-rest-of-jobs
```

In role de-servers-setup role the ssh port is changed from 22 to 8888, so when the last task is called it fails because it cannot connect to host through 22 port. **How to overcome this ssh port change?**

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In the role `de-server-setup` add a task to change the `ansible_port` host variable.

```
- name: Change ssh port to 8888
  set_fact:
    ansible_port: 8888
```

Comment: This would only work if you're running the playbook for the first time, no?

Comment: How would you make this idempotent?

Comment: @Philippe: I have same problem: access using port 22, change port to 1122, go on using new port. I am having trouble being able to make it idempotent

Comment: @realtebo I used something based on [this](https://dmsimard.com/2016/03/15/changing-the-ssh-port-with-ansible/) to solve the problem for me. It's not pretty, but it works.

Answer (score 27):

The only thing I can think of that might work would be to create ssh aliases for your hosts. In your `.ssh/config`:

```
Host de.1.before
  HostName 192.26.32.32
  Port 22

Host de.1.after
  HostName 192.26.32.32
  Port 8888
```

Then use these aliases in your Ansible inventory:

```
[de-servers-before]
de.1.before

[de-servers-after]
de.1.after
```

And the defined groups then respectively in your plays:

```
- name: Install de-servers configurations
  hosts: de-servers-before
  roles:
    - de-server-setup

- name: Install uk-servers configurations
  hosts: uk-servers  
  roles:
    - uk-server-setup

- name: Do some other job on de-servers (cannot be done until uk-servers is installed)
  hosts: de-servers-after
  roles:
    - de-servers-rest-of-jobs
```

Comment: Nice feature of ssh!

Comment: This solution also allows to clearly distinguish a given host, before and after this important change. Not subtle, but explicit, and if the port change is the last of the playbook, then the following ones just need the 'after' name. (On my side, I use `server-0.before` and simply `server-0`)

Answer (score 22):

My full solution to this was to create a common playbook imported at the top of all other playbooks that checks the status of the non-standard `ansible_port` defined in the inventory. If the port is open then continue as normal. If it's not open check port 22 and set the `ansible_port` fact to that if so.

Later, when the SSH server is configured for the first time and the default port is changed to my non-standard port, I then update the `ansible_port` fact manually in my playbook so that any further Ansible connections in the current run will work as expected.

My inventory looks like this:

```
[webservers]
web01.somedomain.com ansible_port=1234
```

My playbook looks like this:

```
- name: Determine SSH port
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: "Check port {{ ansible_port }}"
      wait_for:
        port: "{{ ansible_port }}"
        state: "started"
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        connect_timeout: "5"
        timeout: "5"
      delegate_to: "localhost"
      ignore_errors: "yes"
      register: ssh_port

    - name: "Check port 22"
      wait_for:
        port: "22"
        state: "started"
        host: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        connect_timeout: "5"
        timeout: "5"
      delegate_to: "localhost"
      ignore_errors: "yes"
      register: ssh_port_default
      when: 
        - ssh_port is defined 
        - ssh_port.state is undefined

    - name: Set SSH port to 22
      set_fact:
        ansible_port: "22"
      when: ssh_port_default.state is defined
```

Finally, right after the SSH server is configured and the port has been changed I have this:

```
- name: Set SSH port to 1234
  set_fact:
    ansible_port: "1234"
```

Answer (score 12):

I would suggest to put the port number on the inventory file. Like the following example.

```
[linux-servers]
xcpng5.homelab.com ansible_port=3511
xcpng2.homelab.com ansible_port=3522
xcpng1.homelab.com ansible_port=3523
```

I was trying to achieve the same and that helped me to set up different ssh port.

Comment: if all hosts use the same port use `[all:vars] ansible_port=3511` for example.

Answer (score 9):

Easy way, edit /etc/ansible/hosts:

```
[my_server]
ssdnodes:54321
```

and you can test it by issuing a ping:

```
ansible ssdnodes -m ping
```

and the response would be:

```
ssdnodes | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is my example for connecting with different ssh port using ansible-playbook.

```
---
- hosts: test-server
  vars:
        ansible_ssh_user: 'rohit'
        ansible_password: '123456'
        ansible_port: '2222'
  tasks:
        - name: "print simple command"
          command: cat /usr/bin/myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

I need to change the ssh ports on the hosts I manage and I want to use
Ansible to do it. Essentially, Ansible uses the following logic to manage
it's SSH connections:

```
    if self.port is not None:
        ssh -p {{ self.port }} ...
    else:
        ssh ...
```

where "self.port" is the port specification from the host inventory,
or an override via the "-e" parameter, or an explicit declaration of
the variables "ansible_port" and/or "ansible_ssh_port". The
recommended solution to changing ports is to employ the
"wait_for" and "when" modules in "pre_tasks", but there are many
inadequacies to this approach, particularly when many hosts
are involved and especially when you want to use different ports
on different hosts.

I cloned and patched the ssh plugin (versions 1 and 2) to change
the logic as follows:

```
if self.port is not None and self.port is OPEN:
    ssh -p {{ self.port }} ...
else:
    ssh ...
```

The patch, by itself, makes no changes on the target nodes but
allows connections to succeed even if the ports on the nodes
haven't changed yet. With the patch, it is now very easy to write
roles/tasks to change ssh ports to whatever is in the host
inventory.

If you're interested, you can find the patch and samples
of how use it at https://github.com/crlb/ansible; the
README.md contains additional information.

Answer (score 3):

In your inventory file you can define the ssh port like this

---

[de-servers]

192.26.32.32:8888

[uk-servers]

172.21.1.23:8888

172.32.2.11:8888

Comment: Please provide any description