# How to have an idempotent Ansible playbook if we change the SSH port?

Tags: ssh, ansible

My playbook needs to change the ssh port and updates the firewall rules. (unfortunately, I cannot "get" a new server directly with the desired custom port).

Managing the change [**during** the execution is easy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34336569/125075).

However I do not know how to have an **idempotent** playbook.

- The first run must be initiated on the default port (22).
- The next runs must be initiated on the custom port.

A [solution](https://serverfault.com/a/546897/20442) could be done but with performance issues.

Is there any other possibility with Ansible 2.0+?

Comment: Maybe a `local_action` which modifies `hosts.ini` locally?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could approach this a couple of ways really.

The simplest way might be to simply separate the SSH port configuration into a separate playbook/role that specifies the SSH port as 22 but then your inventory would normally define the SSH port as your custom one.

#### ssh_port.yml

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_ssh_port: 22
  tasks:
   - name: change the default ssh port
     lineinfile ...
     notify: restart ssh

  handlers:
     - name: restart ssh
       service: 
         name : sshd
         state: restarted
```

You would then only run this playbook on the creation of the machine and then only re-run your main playbook again and again, sidestepping the idempotency of this step.

Alternatively, as [Mikko Ohtamaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/315168/mikko-ohtamaa) pointed out in the comments, you could have Ansible modify your inventory file when you change the port. This will mean that you can run the whole thing end to end idempotently as the next run through will connect on the non default SSH port and then simply (pointlessly obviously) check that the SSH port is still set to the desired one. You can get at the inventory file by using the ["magic variable"](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) `inventory_file`. A rough example might look like this:

```
- name: change the default ssh port
  lineinfile ...
  notify: restart ssh

- name: change ssh port used by ansible
  set_fact:
    ansible_ssh_port: {{ custom_ssh_port }}

- name: change ssh port in inventory
  lineinfile:
    dest: inventory_file
    insert_after: '[all:vars]'
    line: 'ansible_ssh_port="{{ custom_ssh_port }}"'
```

Just make sure you have an [inline group variables block](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#group-variables) for `all` in the inventory file and this will mean all future runs of any playbook against this inventory will connect to all of the hosts contained inside it on your custom SSH port.

If you use source control then you will also need a local_action task to push the change back to your remote.