# How to change the port in ansible playbook

Tags: macos, ssh, kubernetes, ansible, minikube

My `inventory` file looks like this;

`minikube`

```
fatal: [minikube]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host minikube port 22: Operation timed out", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
minikube                   : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But the playbook runs in port `22`. I need to change it to `80`. I followed the question, [Ansible change ssh port in playbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333058/ansible-change-ssh-port-in-playbook) I added a task to change the port. But still returns the same error.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, that you're trying to target a minikube VM with Ansible?  Trying to do anything directly on that VM is a little unusual.

Answer (score 2):

You should include the port in your inventory:

```
minikube ansible_port=80
```

This is discussed in Ansible's "[How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)" documentation (which includes examples).